# Where can we find Deligne's paper " Theorie de Hodge I"?

Tags: reference-request, hodge-theory

Where can we find Deligne's paper " Theorie de Hodge I"?

Comment: I would look in my university library, but I assume that's not an option for you?

Comment: MathSciNet says that it is in the proceedings of the 1970 ICM in Nice - http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?b=498552&b=498551&b=441965

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Voici](http://math.harvard.edu/~tdp/Deligne-Theorie.de.Hodge-1-single-page.pdf).

Comment: Link missing? :-)

Comment: It works for me. 

Comment: Any better way to create a link that works on more browsers?   (Just asking out of curiosity --- I do happen to have that ICM volume.)

Comment: I don't see how this could be a browser issue; might you need to install a djvu reader http://djvu.org/ ?

Comment: @David: I can read .djvu on my laptop but the above link yields just a black screen. Is one meant to wait 5 minutes for something to process? 

Comment: @BCnrd: for me the page opened almost instantaneously. The caveat is that the work machine runs Scientific Linux and Firefox. I can also download the file by right-clicking and saving. 

Comment: @BCnrd: As a work around, you can always ctrl/right click on the link to save the file, and then view it outside your browser with your usual djvu viewer.

Comment: I changed the link to a .pdf version of the paper instead.

Comment: Jim: good idea!  Moot now, but good to keep in mind for future mysteries of this sort. 

Comment: I get the file ,thank you very much

Comment: It seems to be no longer available. Given the fact that I couldn't get it online, might you upload it somewhere again?

Comment: @Konrad V: link reactivated!

Comment: there's no cedilla on a c before an i

Comment: No longer working, but there is an [alternative](http://barbra-coco.dyndns.org/yuri/Deligne/Deligne-Theorie-de-Hodge-1.pdf).

Answer (score 25):

Amazingly, ALL the ICM talks since the beginning of time can now be found online at http://mathunion.org/ICM/

Comment: And the scans are of very high quality!

Comment: I just passed by and see that the link is broken...

Comment: The new link to the ICM proceedings is here https://www.mathunion.org/icm/proceedings . Deligne's article begins on page 425 of this volume https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1970.1/ICM1970.1.ocr.pdf

Answer (score 5):

It is in the conference volume of the 1970 ICM at Nice. Not so easy to find online, it seems, if that is what you meant. There is a summary in a review:

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01268-3/S0273-0979-09-01268-3.pdf